# Server ERROR 501- Unsupported method ('POST')

Tags: php, python-3.x, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

**Error I got :**

```
Error response
Error code: 501

Message: Unsupported method ('POST').

Error code explanation: HTTPStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED - Server does not support this operation.
```

**Task I had Done :**

I had started the server from the AWS ec2 instance by using the following command :

```
python3 -m http.server 8000
```

I had created a registration form in the website and I want to post the details of users to the amazon RDS Service.

**What I had Tried :**

So, I had tried the following code in connect.php file to post the user details into the amazon RDS by using the method="post" in the html form attribute :

```
<?php
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $facebook_id = $_POST['facebook_id'];
    $instagram_id = $_POST['instagram_id'];
    $twitter_id = $_POST['twitter_id'];
    $snapchat_id = $_POST['snapchat_id'];
    $linkedin_id = $_POST['linkedin_id']; 
    $youtube_id = $_POST['youtube_id'];
    $telegram_id = $_POST['telegram_id'];

    // Establish database connection
    $conn = new mysqli_connect('[hostlink from amazon RDS]', '[username]', '[password]', '[database name]');

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } else {
        echo "Connected successfully";

        // Prepare SQL statement
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO socialmedia (username, facebook_id, instagram_id, twitter_id, snapchat_id, linkedin_id, youtube_id, telegram_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        
        // Bind parameters
        $stmt->bind_param("ssssssss", $username, $facebook_id, $instagram_id, $twitter_id, $snapchat_id, $linkedin_id, $youtube_id, $telegram_id);

        // Execute the prepared statement
        $stmt->execute();
        
        // Check if the query was successful
        if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0) {
            echo "Data inserted successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: Failed to insert data";
        }

        // Close the prepared statement
        $stmt->close();
    }

    // Close the database connection
    $conn->close();
?>
```

**My expectation:**

I am expecting the modified code if there is any wrong in my code or else please give correct approach for my problem to post the details into RDS

Comment: `python -m http.server` is a fairly simple light weight server.  It does not support POST or running PHP code.  You'll need some other server, or custom extensions to Python's http server, if you want to support that.

Comment: @AnonCoward
would you please tell me the custom extensions that to be used to to python's http server to support my code and if possible please give the modified correct code for my problem